# How to bind a key to sigkill in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, sigkill

I'm developing my application (on Linux) and sadly it sometimes hangs. I can use `Ctrl+C` to send sigint, but my program is ignoring sigint because it's too far gone. So I have to do the process-killing-dance:

```
Ctrl+Z
$ ps aux | grep process_name
$ kill -9 pid
```

Is there a way to configure bash to send the kill signal to the current process when I press - say - `Ctrl+Shift+C`?

Answer (score 10):

I don't think there is any key you can use to send a SIGKILL.

Will SIGQUIT do instead? If you are not catching that, the default is to core dump the process. By default this is ^\. You can see this by running:

```
$ stty -a
```

in a terminal. It should say:

```
quit = ^\
```

Comment: How does this work? If I'm writing a new terminal application should I know about this or is it handled at a lower level?

Comment: It is handled at the tty level in the kernel. When it sees the quit key, it sends a SIGQUIT to the foreground process on that terminal. You can catch SIGQUIT if you want to stop it, but core dumps on demand are quite useful.

Comment: Here I was, like a total newbie, pressing ^ and \  to no effect. The actual buttons should be CTRL \ ... (at least on my machine).

Answer (score 7):

You can send a SIGQUIT signal to the current foreground process by pressing ^\ (by default, you can run `stty -a` to see the current value for `quit`.)

You can also kill the last backgrounded process from the shell by running

```
$ kill %%
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that there's no bound key for SIGKILL, what you can do is to create an alias to save some typing, if SIGQUIT doesn't cut it for you. First, the

```
Ctrl+Z
$ ps aux | grep process_name
$ kill -9 pid
```

dance can be summarized (**if there's only one instance of the process that you want to kill**) as

```
Ctrl+Z
$ pkill -9 process_name
```

if your use case always goes to suspend then kill, you can create an alias to kill the last process ran like

```
$alias pks="pkill -9 !!:0"
```

Add that alias in your ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: Instead of this you could use the 
kill %
which kills the last job

Comment: On linux, killall process_name will kill all processes with that name.  Caution: killall on Solaris and other unixes kills all the processes.